# "502 Bad Gateway" with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I am using rails(2.3.10)/passenger(2.2.15)/nginx(0.7.67) , when i run my application, it give me "502 Bad Gateway" and without any production log, my conf file is :

```
  1 server {
  2     listen  80;
  3     server_name  www.why.bz;
  4     root   /usr/local/apps/why/pro/public;
  5     access_log  /usr/local/apps/why/pro/log/access.log;
  6     passenger_enabled on;
  7 }
```

who can give me some tips, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done Rails deployments full-time for the last couple of years, so hopefully I can help. You've probably figured this problem out by now, but here are some questions to think about for next time:

- Since this is a Ruby on Rails application, can you tell where the error is coming from: Nginx or Rails itself?  That sounds more like a Nginx issue, but it would be good to know. A quicky peek into the Rails production.log or Nginx's error_log should elucidate this info.
- How are you connecting to the application: web browser or command line?  Is the IP and hostname set correctly (try the Linux "dig" command to verify)?  Are you trying to hit http://localhost:80 ?
- There are error log commands that nginx takes that could be configured to help you debug the issue (much like the access_log line): http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log
- Lastly, verify the permissions that are set on your web files: The nginx web server needs to be able to access them.  At least "read" permissions are needed.

Good luck,
Harmon

Comment: Why was this answer chosen? Which thing solved the problem? I have this problem too, and reading this answer does not give clear insight into how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I too have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
listen 443;
```

it could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your secret key base is missing for the required stage.

One thing that I sometimes forget, especially if I don't start with a staging environment and then add it later, is to add the following to my `secrets.yml` file:

```
staging:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

This is telling Rails to get the `secret_key_base` value from the environment variable, `SECRET_KEY_BASE`. You must specify this variable by placing this in your nginx configuration:

```
passenger_env_var SECRET_KEY_BASE yoursupersecretkeybase;
```

If you don't have a `SECRET_KEY_BASE`, you can generate one with:

```
bundle exec rake secret
```